# Add plus sign in spinner (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, spinner

i'm trying to add a sign (+) in my field with spinner but it return each time the number without sign, can i solve this problem somehow?

```
var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    step: 0.25,
    min:-12, 
    max:8, 
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        var ph = $('#spinner').val();
        if(ph.indexOf('+') == 0) {
          alert($('#spinner').val());
          $('#spinner').val('+'+$('#spinner').val());
       } else {

       }
    },
    spin: function( event, ui ) {

    }

});
```

or u can check it here:http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/220/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for spin too:   [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/241/)

```
var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner({
    step: 0.25,
    min: -12,
    max: 8,
    change: function (event, ui) {        
    },
    spin: function (event, ui) {
        var keepPlus =  spinner.val().indexOf('+') === 0?true:false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var ph = spinner.val(); 
            if (ph > 0 && keepPlus)spinner.val('+' + spinner.val());
        }, 0);
    }

});
```

Comment: here it returns evrytime the plus, just waht i want is: if i write the plus it must stay when i spin else if i dont write the plus i spin without plus, but in ur case i have always plus

Comment: cool it work!!!!thanx but i dont understand also ahy ahen i write comma in place of point the value return to 0, but when i write point evrything work fine, do u have an idea how can i fix this too ,thanx in advance

Comment: @GoodD since replacing the point with a comma creates something that isn't a number in javascript, the plugin can't correctly detect what it is. I believe the numberFormat option or culture option can do something about this.

Answer (score 1):

indexOf returns an index, or -1 for not found. You need to compare with -1 rather than 0

```
if(ph.indexOf('+') == -1)
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/223/)</kbd>

However, i suggest going about this an entirely different way. Instead, override the _format method.

```
$.ui.spinner.prototype._format = function(value){
    if (value > 0) {
        return "+" + value;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    step: 0.25,
    min:-12, 
    max:8
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/240/)</kbd>

Now it gets updated both on change and spin, without the ugly jumping, and it works on negative numbers too. Doing this of course means you can't use the Globalize number formatting.

Comment: To add onto this, `indexOf` will return "0" if a match starts on the first character of the string. "+45" would return "0" if searching for "+".

Comment: ok it looks good, but another question why the code don't work when i spin?

Comment: @GoodD it does, if you click off the input to trigger the change event.

Comment: i mean [link]http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/229/ when i spin it dont change nothing, it's only working in the function change but not spin

Comment: If you just use the spinner arrows, the plus sign is not prepended.

Comment: It does when you leave the input, which is exactly how typing into it works.

Comment: My guess is the following: When a number is less than zero, it will have a minus in front. Your code says, "if there's no plus in the string, add a plus", hence you end up with "+-2.5" and javascript cannot parse this, so it restarts at 0 if you try to spin further.

Comment: @Steve Wellens this is actually what im searching almost to solve

Comment: Use the stop event, but you'll notice it's very ugly. http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/231/

Comment: @GoodD  - I know, I was pointing out this answer doesn't solve the problem

Comment: It does solve the problem presented, it just doesn't solve ALL of the problems involved. I think doing this at all is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: i mean when i write a positive number with plus and i spin, the sign plus should be evrytime there else if i dont write any sign it spin normal without the +

Comment: it's somehow not good, the code of @roasted is perfect but it show evrytime the sign

Comment: @GoodD Sorry, i left an extra comma, that would make it break in IE.

Comment: @Kevin try the solution of roasted ,it's exactly what i need

Comment: @GoodD his answer doesn't work at all for me in chrome... odd.

Comment: @GoodD yeah, it doesn't work. + is never added to the output. http://imgur.com/6nJcnOL

Comment: @KevinB  you should read Good D comment on my answer, he doesn't want (+) to be here all the time just when manualy added. He didn't mention that in original question